# Eclipse > the .html file is not opening

Tags: java, eclipse

[image: HTML Poblem]

I am trying to create a simple Web App. When I created my first newFile.html file, it won't show me the content of it, as you can see it in the Image attached below.

Comment: Check your file association for HTML in Eclipse

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try opening the *NewFile.html* with **Html Editor**:

1. Right click on the **NewFile.html**
2. Navigate to **Open With**
3. Select **HTML Editor**

[image]